# Convert 2nd order Butterworth to 1st order - Part II -

Tags: python, filter, butterworth

I'm trying to convert my working 2nd-order Butterworth low pass filter to 1st-order in python, but it gives me very big numbers, like flt_y_1st[299]: 26198491071387576370322954146679741443295686950912.0. Here's my 2nd-order and 1st-order Butterworth:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.signal import lfilter
from scipy.signal import butter

def butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=1):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    return b, a

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=1):
    b, a = butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

def bw_2nd(y, fc, fs):
    filtered_y = np.zeros(len(y))

    omega_c = math.tan(np.pi*fc/fs)
    k1 = np.sqrt(2)*omega_c
    k2 = omega_c**2
    a0 = k2/(1+k1+k2)
    a1 = 2*a0
    a2 = a0
    k3 = 2*a0/k2
    b1 = -(-2*a0+k3)
    b2 = -(1-2*a0-k3)

    filtered_y[0] = y[0]
    filtered_y[1] = y[1]

    for i in range(2, len(y)):
        filtered_y[i] = a0*y[i]+a1*y[i-1]+a2*y[i-2]-(b1*filtered_y[i-1]+b2*filtered_y[i-2])

    return filtered_y


def bw_1st(y, fc, fs):
    filtered_y = np.zeros(len(y))

    omega_c = math.tan(np.pi*fc/fs)
    k1 = np.sqrt(2)*omega_c
    k2 = omega_c**2
    a0 = k2/(1+k1+k2)
    a1 = 2*a0
    k3 = 2*a0/k2
    b1 = -(-2*a0+k3)
#    b1 = -(-2*a0)  # <= Removing k3 makes better, but still not perfect

    filtered_y[0] = y[0]

    for i in range(1, len(y)):
       filtered_y[i] = a0*y[i]+a1*y[i-1]-(b1*filtered_y[i-1])

    return filtered_y

f = 100
fs = 2000
x = np.arange(300)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / fs)

flt_y_2nd = bw_2nd(y, 120, 2000)
flt_y_scipy = butter_lowpass_filter(y, 120, 2000, 1)
flt_y_1st = bw_1st(y, 120, 2000)

for i in x:
    print('y[%d]: %6.3f flt_y_2nd[%d]: %6.3f flt_y_scipy[%d]: %6.3f flt_y_1st[%d]: %8.5f' % (i, y[i], i, flt_y_2nd[i], i, flt_y_scipy[i], i, flt_y_1st[i]))

plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.xlabel('Time [ms]')
plt.ylabel('Acceleration [g]')
lines = plt.plot(x, y, x, flt_y_2nd, x, flt_y_scipy, x, flt_y_1st)
l1, l2, l3, l4 = lines
plt.setp(l1, linewidth=1, color='g', linestyle='-')
plt.setp(l2, linewidth=1, color='b', linestyle='-')
plt.setp(l3, linewidth=1, color='y', linestyle='-')
plt.setp(l4, linewidth=1, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.legend(["y", "flt_y_2nd", "flt_y_scipy", "flt_y_1st"])
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0, 150)
plt.ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
plt.title('flt_y_2nd vs. flt_y_scipy vs. flt_y_1st')
plt.show()
```

... I removed all [i-2]s, which were a feed-forward and a feed-back.

[image: b1 = -(-2*a0+k3)]

However, it seems that's not enough. I think I need to change some equations in a0, b1, etc.  For example, when I remove '+k3' from b1, I get a plot like this (looks better, doesn't it?):

[image: b1 = -(-2*a0)]

I'm not specialized in filters, but at least I know that this 1st order differs from that of scipy.butter. So, please help me find correct coefficients. Thank you in advance.

Here's my reference: [filtering_considerations.pdf](http://biomech.byu.edu/portals/83/docs/exsc663/part01/filtering_considerations.pdf)

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is with the given result? All values seem to be "in the correct range".

Comment: @Jonas Adler The problem is that I get astronomically big numbers, like flt_y_1st[299]: 26198491071387576370322954146679741443295686950912.0. Only when I remove '+k3' from b1, I get a similar plot to yours (but the red peak is 0.07792 in my case). Why does this happen? Am I the only one who gets this? Is there any way to check where is wrong? I will test whatever you ask me. I'm using Python 3.5.1 with Spyder 3.1.0.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is on-topic as it stands. It's not really a programming problem so much as a problem understanding Butterworth filters. That said - have you looked as `scipy`? It has various filters, (including [butterworth](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html)

Comment: @SiHa Actually, I already did it with butter. It works. My goal is not implementing a 1st order Butterworth filter, but simulating/emulating a special tool, which has no source code. I already succeeded in the 2nd order, so now the 1st. Anyway, I have to have my own Butterworth in this way. ... By the way, do you know how to set those coefficients in the 1st order Butterworth?

Comment: I see. Sorry, no I have no idea at all.

Comment: @SiHa No problem at all. Rather, as per your request, I added 'flt_y_scipy'. You reminded me of scipy.butter. Thank you. Now I know that removing '+k3' is not enough.

Comment: You reference document provides the equations for computing the filter coefficients for the 2nd order BW filter. It appears you are trying to use them to compute the first order coeffs as well. I would think there is a separate set specifically for a 1rst order filter. Have you tried reverse engineering the scipy butter function?

Comment: @sizzzzlerz Yes, my reference is for the 2nd order. I'm trying to 'convert' it to the 1st order, as in the title. I also think that there is a separate set for the 1st order, that's why I used a different set for bw_1st. I have tried reverse engineering in scipy.butter, I got [b, a] and [z, p, k], but I don't know how to use them. So, please tell me how to use them I'd prefer, if you gave me a good source for calculating the 1st order Butterworth filter. Please give me something concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer to myself.

The final coefficients are:

```
omega_c = math.tan(np.pi*fc/fs)
k1 = np.sqrt(2)*omega_c
a0 = k1/(math.sqrt(2)+k1)
a1 = a0
b1 = -(1-2*a0)
```

Here's how.
I reverse-engineered them from scipy.butter, as @sizzzzlerz suggested (thanks).
scipy.butter spits out these coefficients:

```
b:  [ 0.16020035  0.16020035]
a:  [ 1.        -0.6795993]
```

Note that **b** and **a** are reversed from my reference. They're gonna be:

```
a0 = 0.16020035
a1 = 0.16020035
b0 = 1
b1 = -0.6795993
```

Then, applied these coefficients to my incomplete formula:

```
a1 = a0 = 0.16020035
b1 = -(1-2*a0) = -{1-2*(0.16020035)} = -(0.6795993)
```

So far, so good.
Incidentally:

```
k1 = 0.2698
k2 = 0.0364
```

So:

```
a0 = k2/(1+k1+k2) = 0.0364/(1+0.2698+0.0364) = 0.0279
```

... This is far from 0.16020035.
At this point, I eliminated k2 and put like this:

```
a0 = k1/(1+k1+x)
```

When x = 0.4142, I got 0.16020164. Close enough.

```
a0 = k1/(1+k1+0.4142) = k1/(1.4142+k1)
```

... 1.4142 ...!? I've ever seen this number before ...:

```
= k1/(math.sqrt(2)+k1)
```

Now the plot looks like this (flt_y_scipy is completely covered by flt_y_1st):

[image: k1/(math.sqrt(2)+k1)]

You can search for the keywords "first order" butterworth "low pass filter" "sqrt(2)", etc.

This is the end of my Sunday DIY. ;-)